# How can I have my RabbitMQ consumer receive just one message without it timing-out and sending agan?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

We have an issue where, if a message takes too long to process, it moves from unacked back to ready and will get sent again. Is there a way to prevent that?

We have a queue consumer class that is initialized this way:

```
    private void Initialize()
    {
        string queueName = _configuration["QueueName"] + _configuration["QueueNameSuffixForSubscriber"];

        var factory = CreateConnectionFactory();

        var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        _channel = connection.CreateModel();

        // The message TTL must match for QueueDeclare() to work.
        var arguments = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        arguments.Add("x-message-ttl", Convert.ToInt32(_configuration["EventBusMessageTtl"]));

        // By default, RabbitMQ dispatches all the messages to the first consumer. You can change this behaviour by
        // setting the BasicQos, this controls the no of messages a consumer can receive before it acknowledges it.
        _channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);

        _channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName, durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: arguments);

        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);
        consumer.Received += ConsumerReceived;

        _channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName, autoAck: false, consumer: consumer);
    }
```

Notice this line:

```
_channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);
```

That's how our consumer just pulls one message at a time. HOWEVER, if that message takes longer than 2 minutes before sending the ack, RMQ will send the message again. We don't want that. (It should almost never happen that it takes more than 2 minutes to process, but we don't want to settle for *almost*.)

Is there a way to stop RMQ from sending the message again? I could send the ack *before* processing the message, but then we'd receive the next message right away and we don't want that either. We want to wait for the message to be done processing before accepting the next message.

If we could just *pull* from RMQ when we're ready, that would solve it.

Here is the `ConsumerReceived()` method:

```
    private void ConsumerReceived(object model, BasicDeliverEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        try
        {
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventArgs.Body.ToArray());
            InvokeHandlers(eventArgs, message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Error occurred in processing message or invoking handlers.");
        }
        finally
        {
            _channel.BasicAck(eventArgs.DeliveryTag, false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: > if that message takes longer than 2 minutes before sending the ack, RMQ will send the message again. 


you must have a bug somewhere. RabbitMQ itself doesn't do anything with the messages, and also I do not recommend to use the `basicget` it is very slow

Comment: If I watch the queue in the Rabbit dashboard, after two minutes I can see the message go from unacked to ready, and is therefore sent again.

Comment: Please try this python script https://gist.github.com/Gsantomaggio/ebeafade515a2788c8553223a4bdb0dc#file-consumer-py you will see that RMQ doesn't resend the message

Comment: Well, I'm seeing it happen. Perhaps it's the way I'm initializing Rabbit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that this seems like an ideal flow for [polling](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html#basic-get) instead of a consumer subscription.  Typically you would not want to poll since it greatly harms throughput, but in your case, that's exactly what you want.

```
while (true)
{
    BasicGetResult result = channel.BasicGet(queueName, noAck);
    if (result == null) 
    {
        // No message available at this time.
        // Sleep/delay to avoid cpu and I/O churn
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    } 
    else 
    {
        try 
        {
            IBasicProperties props = result.BasicProperties;
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.Body.ToArray());
            InvokeHandlers(eventArgs, message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Error occurred in processing message or invoking handlers.");
        }
        finally
        {
            _channel.BasicAck(eventArgs.DeliveryTag, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, right, just do a manual get when ready. Duh. I can try this is a bit. Thank you.

Comment: Just to follow-up on this, I'll leave your answer as the accepted one because it addresses my question. However, I was able to solve this by simply placing the ack *before* handling the message. The event handler `ConsumerReceived()` is *synchronous*, so we can ack and not worry about multiple threads occurring, each having its own message.